# Is there anything like 'whereis' in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, path

I have a line in the code I'm working on like this:

```
feval('func_name', myArg);
```

And it works, but I want to know where `func_name` is. I can't step into `feval` to see where it is finding `func_name`. Instead of (or in addition to) just doing `func_name`, how can I get MATLAB to tell me where it found it?

Comment: You may want to change the line of code to avoid `feval`. You could, instead, write `myFun = str2func('func_name')`, and then evaluate by calling `myFun(myArg)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`which` is the function you're looking for.

See: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/which.html for more. For example:

```
fullpath = which( 'func_name' )
```

Answer (score -1):

func_name is sometimes a file name contains the function to be evaluated on myArg. And it should be in the same directory of the main file unless specified.

Comment: func_name could be anywhere on the MATLAB search path, not just in the same directory... Edric's answer above will tell you where the file is. "unless specified" is also misleading since it implies you could call a function in a different directory...